# Magento Category Flat Data not working or created, how can I force creation of table to show my categories again?

Tags: magento, catalog, flat

The table catalog_category_flat_store_1 has gone/not been created, and I cannot turn on Use Flat Catalogue Category in admin, it is greyed out.

from exception log:

```
2023-06-09T09:10:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Invalid column data type ""
Trace: #0 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(606): Varien_Db_Ddl_Table->addColumn('entity_id', false, NULL, Array, 'entity_id')
#1 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1461): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#2 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1475): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#3 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(260): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#4 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#5 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#6 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(182): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#7 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#8 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
#9 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/phoenixx/public_html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/phoenixx/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

I've checked in phpmyadmin and the table does not exist.

I've tried disabling compilation and reindexing, doesn't help.

I deleted my .lock files in var/locks, that didn't work

I've looked at similar questions for possible help

Also, as a result, Category Flat Data won't reindex "There was a problem with reindexing process. Cannot initialize the indexer process." (I'm guessing because it doesn't exist!). I have run a reindex script from site root, but it doesn't help.